# shuffle merge linked list recursive solution

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to understand linked lists but I got stucked in the following recursive solution. Let a = {1, 2, 3} and b = {4, 5, 6}. With a pen and paper, I have reached to recur pointer. And when the recur is equal to NULL, I started to proceed, but when i came to the line which is `b -> next = recur;` I got confused. Because the previous value of recur was `NULL`, but if it is `NULL`, it means that function ends there but then it is not a recursive function. If I need to go to the line which is `recur = ShuffleMerge(a->next, b->next);` that time the situation got worse. Because `a -> next = NULL` and `b -> next = NULL` , since when we calculated the recur first time, a was 3 and b was 6, so I did not understand how this code works but even when I checked with gdb, it shows that result first 3 and then 2 and finally 1. But I really did not understand that solution. I need some help! Thanks in advance.

```
struct node* ShuffleMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b) {
    struct node* result;
    struct node* recur;
    if (a==NULL) return(b); // see if either list is empty
    else if (b==NULL) return(a);
    else {
        // it turns out to be convenient to do the recursive call first --
        // otherwise a->next and b->next need temporary storage.
        recur = ShuffleMerge(a->next, b->next);
        result = a; // one node from a
        a->next = b; // one from b
        b->next = recur; // then the rest
        return(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: everytime you call the recursive function **new** pointers `result` and `recur` are created. Within the calling function those variables keep their old value.

Comment: i think i can not understand what exactly 'b -> next = recur;' does. Because recur was 'NULL' and ok, recur needs to recalculate and then what will be the function variables?

Comment: Maybe an example helps?? http://pastebin.com/QhVWvbuJ

Comment: very helpful! But i am still not clear about that. Because in gdb, after result, it goes into a loop. it means that result is a variable which is dependent on 'a'. In your code, i understand that recur is just a result not a recursive function. Because 'b -> next' directly is equal to 'a2 -> NULL'. I think it is clear for that code but i can t figure out for a more variable lists.

Comment: Hmmmm ... recursion is used to transform a big problem into smaller and smaller problems, It is a big problem to merge two lists of 100 elements each but it's certain that the merging is the first element of the first list followed by the first element of the second list followed by the result of merging two lists with 99 elements. Same thing for lists with 4 elements. Merging two lists when one of them is empty is just the other list and the recursion stops.

Comment: @pmg thanks again for the example. I am just wondering what will be if 'a1 -> a2 ->NULL' and 'b1 -> b2 -> NULL' .  i think it gets complicated like that? I will be very appreciated if you can modify the example according to this?

Comment: There is nothing complicated (other than thinking recursevily) http://pastebin.com/LqXtCDb7

Comment: i really can not understand what 'b ->next = recur;' does. It goes to ' recur = ShuffleMerge();' line and what happens after that?

Comment: `recur`is just a pointer. `b->next = recur;` changes the value of `b->next` to the value in `recur`, just like `x = y;` changes the value of `x` to the value of `y`

Comment: i cant get the point when **recur = ShuffleMerge(a -> next, b ->next);** . Of course i understand that **b -> next** will take the value of recur but i cant follow how recur changes becaues it also uses ** b -> next ** . I think i need more explanation if possible.

Comment: `recur` is a pointer (like `0x7fffffff75198200`); it doesn't use anything. Each level of recursion has its own `recur`

Comment: After b -> next = recur; line i though that it comes back to recur = ShuffleMerge(); line and recalculates all?

Comment: No, each level of recursion calculates `recur` once only at the line `recur = ShuffleMerge(a->next, b->next);`. It gets a value (0x7fffffff75198200) and that value is used on the line `b->next = recur;`

Comment: i think i am totaly lost right now. Then where is the recursive part? i mean, yes when the ShuffleMerge function starts it comes to recur = ... line and goes into a loop, when the loop ends, recur = NULL, and what i understood from you, it means that b ->next = NULL; and result will be a -> b -> NULL ? But the answer is as in your code should be a1 -> b1 -> a2 -> b2 -> NULL?

Comment: There are as many `recur` as recursive levels. Only the deepest `recur` will be NULL; all the others will point to (part of) the list.

Comment: Finally, i got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: YAY! And now for the fun bit: **to understand recursion you must first understand recursion.**